# How to write function to compare two sets?

Tags: scala

I have type Set = Int => Boolean; , and function subset / how to get two sets A and B and compare them?
I wrote like

```
def union(a: Set, b: Set): Set = {
  (i: Int) => a(i).&(b(i))==b(i) 
  }
```

compiling is successful, but it shows `<function1>` in output when I'm running the code.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to archive, but you get the output like so because you have function `union` which returns a function (which takes i: Int as an input).

Comment: This is a question from the Functional Programming in Scala course I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I gather you're working through some exercises, possibly those from the Coursera course "Functional Programming Principles in Scala" from professor Odersky. If not, you should not be re-defining built-in names such as `Set`.

In any event, to answer you question, having chosen to represent "a set of integers" as a function that returns `true` if the `Int` supplied to it is a member of the set, your set *is* a function (of one `Int` argument returning a `Boolean`).

Scala does not record any source code when it compiles a function to JVM bytecode, so it cannot produce a `String` representing that function in any meaningful way and instead just produces `<functionN>` where *N* is the function's arity (number of arguments).

Answer (score 0):

I can deduct that your `Set` is not a class but it's a type alias for `Int=>Boolean.`

Since `=>` is a syntactic sugar for `FunctionN`, `Set` is a type alias for `Function1[Int,Boolean]`